# Trying to use Dependency Injection in Blazor on Navigation Manager in c# class

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor

I'm trying to use Dependency Injection in order to use the Navigation Manager in a c# class I've created because I'm using a MVVC model. But the [Inject] isn't recognized by Visual Studio. I tried adding a "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" statement, but the only Namespace i get in the suggestion is Mivrosoft.Win32.... . Is it even possible to use the Navigation manager/ inject it in a c# pure class?

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor injection for a class, `[Inject]` attribute works only for components (class deriving from `ComponentBase`)

Comment: Thank, you, but I still got the problem, that the Type NavigationManager can't be found, because the using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components doesn't work. Do you have any recommendation to solve this problem?

Comment: Add the package *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components* to your library